# Printing decimal values as well as phone numbers using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have following data table in MS Excel

```
phone no    cost
1231231221  10.45
1234234232  12.67
1234234453  30.00
```

The code below is printing `phone no` correctly but leaving out the decimal places of cost.

```
for (int rowNum = rowStart-1; rowNum < rowEnd+1; rowNum++) {
    List<String> cellTempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Row rowObj = hssfSheet.getRow(rowNum);
    for (int col = 0; col < columnEnd; col++) {
        Cell cell = rowObj.getCell(col, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
        if (cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
            String cellValue=df.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());

            System.out.println(cellValue);
            cellTempList.add(cellValue.toString());
        } else {
            cellTempList.add(cell.toString()+"");
        }
}
cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
System.out.println(cellDataList);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please initialize the `DecimalFormat` as

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

I think this will solve your problem. 
Cheers.!

Comment: So # after point gives the total  number of decimal points.

for 2 decimals - `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");`

for 5 decimals -  `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");`